# How can you fill a square whit trapezoids?

Tags: geometry

Good day,
My question is how do you fill a square whit trapezoids that dont have a 90 degrees angle.
Thanks for help.

Comment: Can they have 45 degrees angle?

Comment: yes they can. the square needs to be devided into trapeziods and that's it.

Comment: Can they be different sizes? Can there be infinitely many of them?

Comment: Also, can they have different shapes (angles)? Please, clarify the question so it can be reopened

Answer (score 3):

$\phantom{30charactersbuthiddenones}$
[image]

Comment: So infinitely many?

Comment: @almagest: With this construction, yes.

Comment: It can be solved with finitely many trapezoids, unfortunately the question was put on hold before I had a chance to write up the answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, i don't actually know how to use this site and i'm here because i will get a 10 in my math class if i get it. It was simple you can do anything  infinitely and in any shapes just that it can't have a 90 angle. By the way Thanks for an answer Jack.